# Does the Chinese dual SIM iPhone XS work with any SIM card?

Tags: iphone

I am currently in China. I wish to buy the new iPhone XS here. However, I heard that Apple has lock one SIM card slot for Chinese SIM cards only.

If it's real, this purchase is useless because I intend to use two American SIM cards once I come back from China. Can I use two non Chinese SIM cards with a Chinese iPhone XS?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, provided you go for the option where you don't have to choose a carrier, your new iPhone will be unlocked (speaking from experience).

I just bought one from Hong Kong and I am using both my Chinese (since I am in Mainland China) and one from back home (on roaming) and they both work well.

Answer (score 0):

To notice: the Chinese XS do not have the physical dual nano-SIM card feature nor the e-SIM inside ... only the XS MAX and the yet to be released XR got it.